# how to display data from a document to iphone table view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a list of hospitals. The list is a word document where I have lots of hospitals name. I have to display them in table view. I have to hard code the names or there is some other way to take the name from the document and then display in the `UITableView`?

Answer (score 2):

If you just have this document, and you can actually open the document and hardcode it, i would suggest that you convert it to a plist, using some utilities, or even by hand, reading word will require time and i dont suggest to do it for just 1 file

Answer (score 2):

make a plist and save all your hospital name .. and then fetch it and show easily in your table view

Comment: Thanx a lot.... i have used plist.....

Answer (score 1):

Create an `NSArray` of the names of the hospital and display the same in the `UITableview`.